# Using levelplot as a substitute for filled.contour - how to assign z values efficiently

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I want to plot a level plot of a function as a heat map, and I am not sure if I am initializing the grid for the plot in the most efficient way. Currently, I am working with the code below and I am wondering if `grid$z<- wrapper(grid$x,grid$y,MyFunction)` is really the best way to assign the `z`-Values, assuming that `MyFunction` doesn't possibly know what to do with vector-valued arguments.

```
library("lattice")
MyFunction <- function(x,y){
  return(
    dnorm(sqrt(x^2+y^2))
    )
}
wrapper <- function(x, y, my.fun, ...) {sapply(seq_along(x), FUN = function(i) my.fun(x[i], y[i], ...))}
meshstep <- 0.5
x<- seq(-20,20,meshstep)
y <-seq(-20,20,meshstep)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z<- wrapper(grid$x,grid$y,MyFunction)
p<- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 10, xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Distance to the Origin", sub="In pretty Colors"
          colorkey = TRUE, region = TRUE)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MyFunction` is not vectorized you can use `apply` instead of your `wrapper` function:

```
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- apply(grid, 1, FUN=function(XY)MyFunction(XY[1], XY[2]))
```

If `MyFunction` is vectorized you can use `outer`:

```
z <- outer(x, y, MyFunction)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- as.vector(z)
```